# Javascript confirm form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

What is the problem with my code? This is confirm dialog. If the user clicks yes, he/she must navigates to Index view of Work Controller. If user clicks no he/she must navigates to Index view of Product Controller. But navigation does not work!

```
 <input type="button"  onclick="if (confirm('Format the hard disk?'))
$.ajax({
    url: '/Work/Index/24',
    data: { ID: myJSVariable },
    type: 'get',
    traditional: true
});
else {
$.ajax({
    url: '/Product/Index/24',
    traditional: true
})
}" />
```

What is the problem? any other suggestions?

Comment: "Navigation does not work"?  What happens?  Does it do nothing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to navigate you need to use `window.location = "/Work/Index/24"`

If you want to use `$.ajax` to do an asynchonous call you need to add a success function.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success : funcion(result){
        alert('ajax completed successfully');
    }
});
```